# Set Shipping Method Programatically

Tags: magento2.3

I am able to split the order (into two orders) based on the Stock Status but the problem i am facing is when i am trying to set shipping method to the order.

Actually i want to set different Shipping Method to both the order.
e.g. first Order i want to set Shipping as free shipping and 2nd as Flat rate.

Below is the code used to set the shipping method for 2nd order but i am getting **The shipping method is missing. Select the shipping method and try again.**

```
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setShippingAmount($total)
            ->setShippingMethod('flaterate_flaterate');
```

Also Tried Below Code Same Issue. **The shipping method is missing. Select the shipping method and try again.**

```
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Rate

        $this->shippingRate
            ->setCode('flaterate_flaterate')
            ->setCarrierTitle($carrierTitle)
            ->setPrice($total);

        $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();

        $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                        ->collectShippingRates()
                        ->setShippingMethod('flaterate_flaterate');

        $quote->getShippingAddress()->addShippingRate($this->shippingRate);
```

Comment: Is flatrate method enabled ?

Comment: yes it is enabled and loading in shipping method list as well

Comment: Was it because of the typo (flaterate) in flatrate?

Comment: Any update about this? I have exactly the same problem, but only if the shipping destination is a foreign country. And yes I allowed the country in the settings...